# Checking if string contains unusual characters using ".contain"

Tags: java, conditional-statements, compare, character

I'm trying to create a simple program in JAVA to identify if a user input string contains a special character for example "!", and if it does it appends it to arrayList1 if it does not it appends the string to arrayList2

i've been told that i can use the new .contain method to determine if the user string input contains a pre defined unusual symbol.

i've been putting in example inputs like he!!o but it isn't read as a string with a special character.

here's the code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //do {  
        System.out.println("enter passswords");
        
        answer= input.nextLine();
        String SimpleSymbol="!@#$%^&*()_+";
        if(answer.contains(SimpleSymbol)) {
            arrayList2.add(answer);
            System.out.println("with special numbers" + arrayList2);         
        } else {
            arrayList1.add(answer);
            System.out.println("without SP" + password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int spChars = answer.replaceAll("[^!@#$%^&*()_+]", "").length(); if (spChars != 0) { System.out.println("Has " + spChars + " Special Characters!"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex match for pattern match.

Try below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        //do {
        System.out.println("enter passswords");

        answer = input.nextLine();
        Pattern pattern
                = Pattern.compile("[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/|}{~:]");
        if (pattern.matcher(answer).find()) {
            arrayList2.add(answer);
            System.out.println("with special numbers" + arrayList2);
        } else {
            arrayList1.add(answer);
            System.out.println("without SP" + answer);
        }
    }
```

References:

1. [Pattern Matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-contains-special-character/)
2. [How to use String.contains() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-contains-method-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```java
String regex = ".*[!@#$%^&*()_+].*";
if (answer.matches(regex)) {
    arrayList2.add(answer);
    System.out.println("with special numbers" + arrayList2);
} else {
    arrayList1.add(answer);
    System.out.println("without SP" + password);
}
```